# Nginx unresponsive under load

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

After switching from haproxy to nginx, one of my reverse proxies has a problem. At a certain number of connections the server stops accepting new requests (closed by timeout). However, if you connect from another external ip address everything works. Backend is fine. In nginx logs:

```
2023/12/08 16:13:50 [debug] 96834#96834: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2023/12/08 16:13:50 [debug] 96861#96861: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2023/12/08 16:13:50 [debug] 96860#96860: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2023/12/08 16:13:50 [debug] 96858#96858: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2023/12/08 16:13:50 [debug] 96847#96847: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Searching the logs led me to an article that advised to increase the kernel limits. But they are already increased on the server.

```
net.core.bpf_jit_enable = 1
net.core.bpf_jit_harden = 1
net.core.bpf_jit_kallsyms = 0
net.core.busy_poll = 0
net.core.busy_read = 0
net.core.default_qdisc = pfifo_fast
net.core.dev_weight = 64
net.core.dev_weight_rx_bias = 1
net.core.dev_weight_tx_bias = 1
net.core.message_burst = 10
net.core.message_cost = 5
net.core.netdev_budget = 600
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 500000
net.core.netdev_rss_key = 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
net.core.netdev_tstamp_prequeue = 1
net.core.optmem_max = 40960
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.rps_sock_flow_entries = 0
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
net.core.warnings = 1
net.core.wmem_default = 4194394
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.core.xfrm_acq_expires = 30
net.core.xfrm_aevent_etime = 10
net.core.xfrm_aevent_rseqth = 2
net.core.xfrm_larval_drop = 1
```

UPDATE. My config nginx:

```
worker_processes  auto;

timer_resolution 100ms;
worker_priority -15;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

error_log  /opt/nginx/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  100000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on; 
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nodelay         off;
    tcp_nopush          on;

    keepalive_timeout 30 15;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 120;

    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
    server_names_hash_max_size 1024;

    proxy_next_upstream error invalid_header timeout http_500 http_502 http_504;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 256 32k;
    gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        application/atom+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_proxied            expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;


        proxy_cache_path /tmp/ram/ levels=1:2 use_temp_path=off keys_zone=level-1:20m max_size=26000m inactive=1440m;
        proxy_temp_path /etc/nginx/proxy_temp;
        proxy_cache_key $server_name$request_uri;

    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 128k;

    proxy_redirect   off;
    proxy_set_header Range "";
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_connect_timeout 15;
    proxy_send_timeout    40;
    proxy_read_timeout    66;
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   8 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `worker_connections`  directive in the nginx.conf?

Comment: Yes. I've tried applying such directives: 
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000
worker_connections  100000

Comment: Also the worker processes? Adjust the number of worker processes based on your server's CPU cores. Too few may lead to inefficiency, and too many may cause contention. Here is some extra guidance https://gist.github.com/v0lkan/90fcb83c86918732b894

Comment: I added my nginx config above

Comment: This one is also important # Also set `
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#   web soft nofile 65535
#   web hard nofile 65535
# /etc/default/nginx
#       ULIMIT="-n 65535" `

Comment: I have nofile set

# cat /etc/security/limits.conf
*          soft     nofile      99999
*          hard    nofile      99999

# ulimit -Hn
99999